# navigation and sub navigation have different position on different screens

Tags: html, css

So I have a nav and a sub nav....

```
<div class="headerNav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='galleryNavToggle'>Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='galleryNavInfoToggle'>Info</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNav-->

<div class="headerNavGallery" id="headerNavGallery" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="Categories.php?action=view">Categoies</a></li>
<li><a href="Products.php?action=view">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNavGallery-->

<div class="headerNavInfo" id="headerNavInfo" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="willRuppel.php?action=view">William Ruppel</a></li>
<li><a href="CV.php?action=view">CV</a></li>
<li><a href="artistBio.php?action=view">Artist Bio</a></li>
<li><a href="Video.php?action=view">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php?action=view">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNavInfo-->
```

and their CSS

```
.headerNav {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-top: 148px;
}

.headerNavGallery {
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.headerNavInfo {
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 177px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

my question is how do I get them to stay in the same position on every screen, no matter the width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a wrapper element ? You can use a parent element as the first child of the body element and include there all your html.

You then can give this wrapper element a spesific wifth (960px) is very common and also center it to the screen like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#wrapper{
 margin:0 auto;
 width: 960px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <!-- ALL YOUR HTML HERE -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```